# Hadoop: Why Hive works so slow even on a tiny table?

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive

I use JDBC from Scala to get data from Hive. In Hive I have a simple table with 20 rows in the following format:

user_id, movie_title, rating, date

To group users by movie I do 3 nested select requests:

```
1) select distinct user_id  
     2) for each user_id: 
         select distinct movie_title  //select all movies that user saw
            3) for each movie_title:
                select distinct user_id  //select all users who saw this movie
```

On a local Hive table with 20 rows these nested queries work 26 min! Hive returns first `user_id` after a minute! Questions:

1)Why Hive is so slow?

2) Any way to optimize 3 nested selects?

Answer (score 0):

Hive uses the MapReduce framework to process queries.  There is a decent amount of constant overhead attached to every MapReduce job you run.  Each of your queries (which is a fair amount because of your nesting) is going to have to spin up a MapReduce job and that takes time regardless of how much data you have.

Newer versions of Hive are much more responsive, but still not ideal for this type of selection.

Your best bet is to try to minimize the number of queries by using `group by` or something similar.

Comment: Thanks! I tried, but can not figure out how to use `group by` in this case.

Comment: Can you add a bit more detail about the final result you want?  Maybe an example output?

Comment: Table contains movie titles rated by users: `user_id, movie_title, rating, date`. I start first JDBC cursor enumerating users. Next, JDBC cursor 2, for every user I find movie titles he rated. Next, JDBC cursor 3, for every title the current user rated, I find other users who also rated this title. As a result I get a group of users where every user rated at least one similar title with the first user who started this group. I need to get all such groups existing in the dataset.

Comment: Interesting.  I would almost suggest you make another question (not specific to Hive) to see if you can find a way to optimize that query.  Or do a custom map/reduce.  Or maybe a Pig script.

Answer (score 0):

Create two tables by inserting records into them based on select distinct queries. First containing distinct user, movie rated where user_rated = user, second, movie_rated = movie. That way, these two tables can be joined to get the desired group by result.